# Deriving moment of inertia of a solid sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, integration, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

I have been trying to calculate it on my own, but the answer I get is different to the one I can find everywhere else, so I have to be wrong.

My attempt was a very straightforward one. I used spherical coordinates to integrate all over the sphere. The convention I use for spherical coordinates is $(r,\theta,\phi)$, with $0\lt \theta \lt \pi$ and $0 \lt \phi \lt 2\pi$. Supposing we have a solid sphere of radius R, mass M uniformly distributed with a volumetric mass density of $\rho=M/V$, and an axis going through its center:

$$I=\int_M r^2 dm = \int_V \rho r^2 dV = \rho \int_{sphere}r^4\sin\theta dr d\theta d\phi=$$
$$\frac{M}{V}\int_0^R r^4 dr \int_0^\pi \sin \theta d \theta \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi=\frac{3M}{4\pi R^3}\cdot \frac{R^5}{5}\cdot 2 \cdot 2\pi=$$
$$\frac{3}{5}MR^2$$

The answer given everywhere else is $I=\frac{2}{5}MR^2$. Since my answer is $3/2$ times bigger than expected, my first thought was that I didn't take into consideration something about the symmetry of the sphere and calculated something redundant. But since every triplet $(r,\theta,\phi)$ refers to a unique point in space, I don't see why that would be the case. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Yes, there is something wrong in the calculations. You integrated $r^2$ on a sphere of radius $R$, considering $r$ as the distance from its centre. But pay attention, because to calculate the moment of inertia you must consider \textit{the distance from the axis of rotation}. Hope this hint leads you to the solution, if it doesn't, I'll give you the solution

Comment: $r$ in the moment of inertia formula is not the same $r$ as your spherical coordinate. This is your mistake.

Comment: @Chronicler "... if it doesn't, I'll give you the solution". Please don't give out solutions here.

Comment: @Chronicler oh, okay! I had been solving problems with cylindrical symmetry, where the line of reasoning I mentioned yielded the right answer. You're right, I missed that detail. I'll integrate the disk as a collection of infinitesimal disks. Thanks!

Comment: Or you could use the fact that the distance from the z-axis is given by $r\sin\theta$

Comment: I was trying to find that precise bit of information because that approach came to mind, and I could imagine it (the distace would be zero in the poles defined by the axis and would reach a maximum in the equator), but couldn't prove why. It was just an intuitive thought, so thanks! Do you know where I can see the proof?

Comment: The derivation is easily found from internet search, eg http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/isph.html#sph2 or https://www.miniphysics.com/uy1-calculation-of-moment-of-inertia-of-solid-sphere.html